# How to define a neural network that maps a 2D real-valued matrix to a 2D binary matrix using Kera?

Tags: neural-networks, loss-functions, matrix

I'm doing some tests with matrix to matrix neural networks.

In my setting, I'm trying to develop a neural network that can map a real-valued matrix to a binary matrix. The input matrix is a random distribution of real numbers. The output matrix indicates, for each line, which is the smallest value of the input matrix. That is, if in the input matrix, the column j has the smallest value for the line x, the cell in of the output matrix would have the value 1, and for all other columns, the line x would have the value 0.

Bellow I will provide an example of a 3X3 input and output matrix.

Input:

[[0.5,0.6,0.2], [0.1,0.5,0.9], [0.5,0.4,0.6]]

Output:

[[0,0,1], [1,0,0], [0,1,0]]

This is a trivial problem that can be easily solved by a simple and straightforward algorithm. But I'm interested in trying to solve this by using neural networks, for gaining insights into how to work with 2D matrices as inputs and outputs. Notice that I'm not interested in working with rows separately. The idea is to build a neural network that has a 2d real-valued input and outputs a 2d binary matrix.

I've developed a scrip (bellow) for generating random datasets and for building and training a neural network. But the achieved accuracy is very low. I think that I'm using the wrong activation function for the last layer of the network, and the wrong loss function for the training. Which would be the best choices for activation and loss functions in this context?

Notice that I'm interested in taking a 2D matrix as the input of my neural network model and having as output a 2D matrix. The idea is not to deal with rows separately. I would like to do something similar to what is done in image-to-image neural networks, but with matrices that are representing non-visual information.

My script:

```
import os
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
import random
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def randomMatrix(matrixSize,maxValue):
    matrix = []
    for i in range(matrixSize):
        line = []
        for j in range(matrixSize):
            value = (random.random()*maxValue)
            line.append(value)
        matrix.append(line)
    return np.array(matrix)
    
def generatesOutputFromInput(matrix):
    output = []
    rows, cols = matrix.shape
    for i in range(rows):
        line = []
        minVal = matrix[i,0]
        for j in range(cols):
            value = matrix[i,j]
            if value < minVal:
                minVal = value
        for j in range(cols):
            value = matrix[i,j]
            if value == minVal:
                line.append(1)
            else:
                line.append(0)
        output.append(line)
    return np.array(output)

def builtDataset(datasetSize,matrixSize,maxValue):
    inputs = []
    outputs = []
    for i in range(datasetSize):
        inputM = randomMatrix(matrixSize,maxValue)
        outputM = generatesOutputFromInput(inputM)
        inputs.append(inputM)
        outputs.append(outputM)
    return np.array(inputs),np.array(outputs)
    
matrixSize = 5
maxValue = 200
epochs = 20
datasetSize = 200000

inputs,outputs = builtDataset(datasetSize,matrixSize,maxValue)
print("inputs ",len(inputs))
print("outputs ",len(outputs))

print(inputs[0])
print(outputs[0])

seed = 7
np.random.seed(seed)
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(inputs, outputs, test_size=0.1, random_state=seed)

es = EarlyStopping(monitor='loss', mode='min', verbose=1,min_delta=0.01, patience=20)
lr_schedule = keras.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay(initial_learning_rate=0.001, decay_steps=1600, decay_rate=0.95)
rmsprop = keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=lr_schedule, momentum=0.3)

model = keras.models.Sequential([
        keras.layers.Dense((matrixSize*matrixSize)/2, input_shape=(matrixSize,matrixSize), activation="relu"),   
        keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
        keras.layers.Flatten(),
        keras.layers.Dense((matrixSize*matrixSize)/4, activation="relu"),
        keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
        keras.layers.Dense((matrixSize*matrixSize)/2, activation="relu"), 
        keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
        keras.layers.Dense(matrixSize*matrixSize, activation="sigmoid"),
        keras.layers.Reshape((matrixSize, matrixSize))
])

model.compile(optimizer=rmsprop,loss="mean_squared_error", metrics=["accuracy"])
model.summary()

history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=100, callbacks=[es], shuffle=True, epochs=epochs, validation_split=0.1)

score = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, verbose=0)
print("Test loss:", score[0])
print("Test accuracy:", score[1])

plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'])
plt.title('model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('model loss')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please don't re-post closed questions. Instead, edit them to make it clear. In this case, we have a lengthy comment thread that tries to understand what your question is asking about. Deleting that question destroys these comments.

Comment: I had already edited the question with details, but it was closed. So, I don't know what this community want. Which details are lacking? I have explicitly said everything relevant.

Comment: Your question is posed as determining if a value is the minimum in the row... But you don't actually want to look at the values by rows. I proposed a neural network that will give the desired result -- but apparently that's also not acceptable, because it... looks at the rows? It seems like you're asking for a square circle: a neural network that can know about row-level information without being given information about rows. You've also said that this isn't the real or main problem that you want to solve, so I think it would make more sense to describe that problem instead!

Comment: My question is about:
(1)How to map 2d matrices to 2d matrices using a neural network, without any other algorithmic workaround.
(2)In this context, I have proposed a toy problem, where I need to find the minimum value of each row.
(3)But I want to do it by feeding the neural network with all information of the matrix at once. That is, the information of the row-level is included in this package of information.
(4)And I want that the neural network outputs the results of all rows at once, with all the information of the matrix.

Comment: So why is my suggestion of a dense neural network not a solution to this?

Comment: Where is your solution? I didn't find it.

Comment: I would like to do something similar to what is done in image-to-image neural networks, but with matrices that are representing non-visual information.